# How to set up URL redirection on D-Link router for specific domain?

Tags: dns, router, dsl, cisco, dnsmasq

I have a D-Link router and I'm looking to set up URL redirection for a specific domain. Specifically, I want all requests made to "https://somesite.com" to be redirected to "https://google.com". Can someone provide step-by-step instructions or guidance on how to achieve this using the configuration interface of a D-Link router? Any insights or tips would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!